# Worried first time DM/general player of DnD seeking advice!

Tags: gm-techniques, new-players

### I need whatever help I can get with my first ever DnD session!

To be honest, I have little to no experience with roleplaying games. I used to roleplay with my friends, but I wouldn't consider that experience in the world of DnD. I got introduced to DnD through The Adventure Zone, Stranger Things, and other pop culture references to the game. Since my family are the ones I'm most comfortable sharing my nerdy interests with, and they're, uh, *older*, I'll be DMing for my parents and my brother. My family is also entirely new to DnD, and I'm not really sure how to prepare them in advance.

I bought the starter kit along with some dice (to treat myself), I'm currently reading through the starter kit manuals, and I'm watching whatever video or post I can find related to DnD. But from what I hear, it's very difficult to DM and listening to podcasts make me so overwhelmed to start.

I just need whatever advice I can get, and whatever information I should read on too, besides the rule book and story that comes with the starter kit. Anything I could be missing, or something to ease my worries.

Thank y'all so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. This is quite a broad question, and *"How do I DM a tabletop game"* is a question with many possible answers.  Are you using D&D 5e?  Have you looked for advice on [forums](/questions/5449)? It may help to narrow your question to a specific aspect of DMing that's troubling you.

Comment: Hello mintyjj and welcome to our site! Once you have 20 reputation, you can join our [chat] where we can offer you informal and personal advice.

Comment: Seems like a 'How do I get started?' question, which is explicitly listed as *not* too broad, but it may benefit from being reworded as more obviously such.

Comment: As currently stated this seems like a duplicate of the linked question, unless you can focus down on a more specific concern?